# Update regex to not break sonar rule

Tags: java, regex, sonarlint

I use this code to create a Map of key value pairs :

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class PatternMatchTest {

    private static final Pattern keyValuePattern = Pattern.compile("\\p{Alnum}+ *=(?: *\\p{Alnum}+)+");
    private static final Pattern quotesPattern = Pattern.compile("\"(.*?)\"", Pattern.DOTALL);

    public static void main(final String[] args){

        final String line = "\"$0 = test 1, $1 = test2, $2 = test3\"";
        final Map<String, String> mappedValues = new HashMap<>();

        final Matcher quotesMatcher = quotesPattern.matcher(line);
        if (quotesMatcher.find()) {
            final String valueInQuotes = quotesMatcher.group(0).replace("$", " ").replace(" = ", "=");
            final Matcher matcher = keyValuePattern.matcher(valueInQuotes);
            while (matcher.find()) {
                final String[] elements = matcher.group().split("=");
                mappedValues.put(elements[0], elements[1]);
            }

        }

        mappedValues.entrySet().forEach(entry -> {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "->" + entry.getValue());
        });

    }
}
```

The string `"\"$0 = test 1, $1 = test2, $2 = test3\""` is converted to a `key->value` map containing :

```
0->test 1
1->test2
2->test3
```

This works as expected but breaks sonar line rule S5998 :

```
The Java regex engine uses recursive method calls to implement backtracking. Therefore when a repetition inside a regular expression contains multiple paths (i.e. the body of the repetition contains an alternation (|), an optional element or another repetition), trying to match the regular expression can cause a stack overflow on large inputs. This does not happen when using a possessive quantifier (such as *+ instead of *) or when using a character class inside a repetition (e.g. [ab]* instead of (a|b)*).
The size of the input required to overflow the stack depends on various factors, including of course the stack size of the JVM. One thing that significantly increases the size of the input that can be processed is if each iteration of the repetition goes through a chain of multiple constant characters because such consecutive characters will be matched by the regex engine without invoking any recursion.
For example, on a JVM with a stack size of 1MB, the regex (?:a|b)* will overflow the stack after matching around 6000 characters (actual numbers may differ between JVM versions and even across multiple runs on the same JVM) whereas (?:abc|def)* can handle around 15000 characters.
Since often times stack growth can’t easily be avoided, this rule will only report issues on regular expressions if they can cause a stack overflow on realistically sized inputs. You can adjust the maxStackConsumptionFactor parameter to adjust this.
Noncompliant Code Example
  Pattern.compile("(a|b)*"); // Noncompliant  Pattern.compile("(.|\n)*"); // Noncompliant  Pattern.compile("(ab?)*"); // Noncompliant  
Compliant Solution
  Pattern.compile("[ab]*"); // Character classes don't cause recursion the way that '|' does  Pattern.compile("(?s).*"); // Enabling the (?s) flag makes '.' match line breaks, so '|\n' isn't necessary  Pattern.compile("(ab?)*+"); // Possessive quantifiers don't cause recursion because they disable backtracking  
Parameters
Following parameter values can be set in Rule Settings. In connected mode, server side configuration overrides local settings.
maxStackConsumptionFactor  
An indicator approximately proportional to how quickly the stack grows relative to the input size. An issue will be reported if the value for a regex exceeds the maximum set here. Setting this to 0 will cause an issue to be reported for all regular expressions with non-constant stack consumption.
Current value: 5.0
Default value: 5.0
```

Removing `+` from the regex fixes the sonar reporting issue but breaks the parsing as values that contain a space do not match correctly.

The regex `\\p{Alnum}+ *=(?: *\\p{Alnum}+)` matches :

```
0->test 
1->test2
2->test3
```

How to update the regex `\\p{Alnum}+ *=(?: *\\p{Alnum}+)+` to match key values pairs where the value can contain a space but also not break the sonar rule S5998 relating to a stackoverflow for large inputs (described above) ?

Comment: There is a problem with `"\\p{Alnum}+ *=(?: *\\p{Alnum}+)+"`, and to resolve it, you need `"\\p{Alnum}+ *= *\\p{Alnum}+(?: +\\p{Alnum}+)*"` or `"\\p{Alnum}+ *= *\\p{Alnum}+(?: +\\p{Alnum}+)* *"`. However, I suspect it will still "breal" S5998 or other Sonar* rules as they are too "pedantic", someone did not do a very good job when implementing them, and they raise false alarm in many cases.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks, yes those regex's you suggest - "\\p{Alnum}+ *= *\\p{Alnum}+(?: +\\p{Alnum}+)*" or "\\p{Alnum}+ *= *\\p{Alnum}+(?: +\\p{Alnum}+)* *" also break S5998

Comment: Yes, but there are absolutely safe to use. Remove this sonarqube, it is evil. Disable this rule. Ignore it. It qualifies safe regexps as "dangerous", but this is just badly written software.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I don't understand regex well to understand why it is safe to use. Is there an article that describes the false positive sonar result in this case or do I just need to understand regex better ?

Comment: You need to understand regex, how it matches strings and what backtracking is.